# Can LINQ (to SQL) do bitwise queries?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, bitmask

I have a table of Users that includes a bitmask of roles that the user belongs to. I'd like to select users that belong to one or more of the roles in a bitmask value. For example:

```
select *
from   [User]
where  UserRolesBitmask | 22 = 22
```

This selects all users that have the roles '2', '4' or '16' in their bitmask. Is this possible to express this in a LINQ query? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will work, but I haven't tested it.Substitute the name of your DataContext object. YMMV.

```
from u in DataContext.Users
where UserRolesBitmask | 22 == 22
select u
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I'd tried that - must of been getting late... :)

Answer (score 13):

As a side note though for my fellow googlers:
`UserRolesBitmask | 22 == 22` selects all users that don't have any other flags (its not a filter, its like saying `1==1`).

What you want is either:

- `UserRolesBitmask & 22 == 22` which selects users which have all the roles in their bitmask or:
- `UserRolesBitmask & 22 != 0` which selects users which have at least one of the roles in their bitmask

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work you could always use `ExecuteCommand`:

```
DataContext.ExecuteCommand("select * from [User] where UserRolesBitmask | {0} = {0}", 22);
```